# Terraform aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment "Error: Missing required argument"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

## Background

I have a Terraform script that creates several different AWS resources and links them together.  One component is the aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.  It has the required parameters, and lots of settings for configuration.  The beginning of the file is thus:

```
data "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "myapp" {
  name = "beanstalkapp"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalk" {
  name                = "beanstalk-environment"
  application         = data.aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.myapp.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.2.5 running Node.js 12"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:instances"
    name = "InstanceTypes"
    value = "t2.micro"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name = "EnvironmentType"
    value = "LoadBalanced"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name = "LoadBalancerType"
    value = "application"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name = "ServiceRole"
    value = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = var.createNewVPC ? aws_vpc.vpc_new[0].id : var.vpc_id_existing
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "Subnets"
    value     = var.createNewSubnets ? "${aws_subnet.subnet_private_a_new[0].id},${aws_subnet.subnet_private_b_new[0].id}" : "${var.subnet_private_a_id},${var.subnet_private_b_id}"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "ELBSubnets"
    value     = var.createNewSubnets ? "${aws_subnet.subnet_public_a_new[0].id},${aws_subnet.subnet_public_b_new[0].id}" : "${var.subnet_public_a_id},${var.subnet_public_b_id}"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name = "MinSize"
    value = "2"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name = "MaxSize"
    value = "2"
  }
  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application"
     name      = "Application Healthcheck URL"
     value     = "/"
  }
  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
     name      = "DB_HOST"
     value     = data.aws_db_instance.myDB.address
  }
  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
     name      = "DB_USER"
     value     = random_password.rds_username.result
  }
  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
     name      = "DB_PASS"
     value     = random_password.rds_password.result
  }
  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
     name      = "DB_PORT"
     value     = data.aws_db_instance.myDB.port
  }
  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
     name      = "CACHE_ADDRESS"
     value     = data.aws_elasticache_cluster.myCache.cluster_address
  }
  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
     name      = "CACHE_PORT"
     value     = var.cache_port
  }
}
```

## Problem

When running the script with -target=aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.beanstalk, the beanstalk deploys just fine.
When running the script to deploy the full stack, the other components are created and then I get

```
Error: Missing required argument

  on beanstalk.tf line 6, in resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalk":
  6: resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalk" {

The argument "setting.1.value" is required, but no definition was found.
```

I'm probably as adapt at deciphering cryptic error messages as the next guy, but this seems like something in the guts of Terraform that is choking.  I was on 0.13.5 and had the error, so I upgraded to 0.14.6.  The only difference is now it displays the line about "setting.1.value".

Any ideas on what this means or how to solve it?

Comment: The error is about `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.beanstalk`, but you are showing different eb: `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.myenvironment`.

Comment: @Marcin My apologies; I had modified the displayed names from the real ones and failed to update that one properly.

Comment: You have only one `setting` block in your EB definition? I think the error is about some other `setting` block.

Comment: The error suggests that there is something wrong with your `setting` blocks. Without seeing them, its difficult to check what can be the issue.

Comment: @Marcin Updated.

Comment: This seems fine, assuming all these `vars` used have correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the setting block that causes the problem:

```
  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
     name      = "CACHE_ADDRESS"
     value     = data.aws_elasticache_cluster.myCache.cluster_address
  }
```

If I replace the value with a static value, everything works.
I believe this to be an issue with Terraform itself returning the proper value of the cluster_address.
**The issue arises because this ElastiCache is a Redis instance, but the cluster_address property is only for Memcached.**
It seems that Terraform should have a better error messge for this.

So if you see a weird "setting.x.value" error, it probably means that you are trying to use something that only applies to *some* of the options available for the resource.